# React JS Open AI Run server exit code 1 with npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I used WebStylePress' tutorial video on how to Build Your Own AI App in React. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2rvIO4n92s. I am getting the weirdest error I can't find anywhere else. My 'npm run server exited with code 1' but only after I have fully entered the question into the ai and pressed enter as it goes to load. It begins the loading and it pauses in the middle and exits. No error codes or errors attached besides status code 429 at the beginning but then it continues. My code is identical to the videos. Here is the github code https://github.com/webstylepress/chatgpt-react-js/tree/main
attached is my exit code

I have updated npm and dependencies and removed and reinstalled node modules.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/keEiL.png

```
[0]         _parentWrap: undefined,
[0]         _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
[0]         reading: true,
        onkeylog: [Fnpm run server exited with code 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: all the code is int he github